# MixedMode DLLs in Unit Tests - Visual Studio Quality Tools

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm facing a situation where I'm getting the following error:

The solution is to set this in the app.config:

```
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
```

I've put this into the app.config file however, I'm running unit tests at the moment.  I've added it to the test library config file but the Visual Studio unit test tools seem to be ignoring this setting and still throwing the error.

How or where do I need to set this in order to get Quality Tools to actually use this setting when running tests?

Comment: I have the same problem, have you solved this? Thx

Comment: Yes I have and I cannot remember how now!  Let me ask the team, someone may remember.